# Image copy merge not working

Tags: php, php-gd

this is code I run, the complete file

```
<?php $image1 = imagecreatefrompng('a.png'); //300 x 300 
$image2 = imagecreatefrompng('b.png'); //150 x 150
imagecopymerge($image1, $image2, 0, 0, 75, 75, 150, 150, 50); ?>
```

What am I missing? Do i need to require something or what?

Comment: whats not working and what is your problem ?

Comment: whats the value returned by the function call `true`or `false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from imagecopymerge() is simply true or false (as per the PHP manual located at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php).

Therefore the script will not output anything to the browser. If you are trying to output to the browser change the script to be:

```
   <?php
   $source = imagecreatefrompng('a.png'); 
   $destination = imagecreatefrompng('b.png');
   imagecopymerge($destination, $source, 0, 0, 75, 75, 150, 150, 50);

   //Output the correct header to the browser
   header('Content-Type: image/png');

   //Output the image
   imagepng($destination);
   ?>
```

alternatively if you would prefer to save the image to a file you could do:

```
   <?php
   $source = imagecreatefrompng('a.png'); 
   $destination = imagecreatefrompng('b.png');
   imagecopymerge($destination, $source, 0, 0, 75, 75, 150, 150, 50);

   //Output the correct header to the browser
   header('Content-Type: image/png');

   //Path to save the image too
   $path = '/path/to/where/i/want/to/save/';
   //Save the image
   imagepng($destination, $path);
   ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it, one more q: how do I save it as file on server?

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example for saving. The imagepng() simply takes another input to specify the path. Please note that this only works with PNG, if you are using JPG or GIF be sure to use the images specifically for those extensions.

Comment: the first code works perfectly, but second one does nothing, it does not save anything to given path.. any solution?

Comment: Try enabling error reporting. Also have you double checked the permissions for the folder you are saving the image too.